# Whats the difference in two lists?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list that i used regex on to remove the spaces in strings in the list which works perfectly -

```
newrooms = re.sub(r'\s+', " ", str(newrooms))
```

the original list looks like -

```
[['4      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['5      10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['8      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['9      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['10      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['10      11-12pm', 'MR251 (22)'], ['12      10-11am', 'MR107 (63)'], ['12      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['17      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['18      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['19      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['19      11-12pm', 'MR265 (24)'], ['20      10-11am', 'CB203 (26)'], ['20      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['27      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['28      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['29      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['42      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['42       2-4pm                MA ONLY', 'MR252 (30)'], ['43      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['44      10-11am', ''], ['44      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]
```

print newrooms[3] prints ... "['9      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']"

after using the re.sub to remove the spaces the list looks like

```
[['4 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['5 10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['8 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['9 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['10 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['10 11-12pm', 'MR251 (22)'], ['12 10-11am', 'MR107 (63)'], ['12 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['17 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['18 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['19 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['19 11-12pm', 'MR265 (24)'], ['20 10-11am', 'CB203 (26)'], ['20 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['27 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['28 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['29 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['42 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['42 2-4pm MA ONLY', 'MR252 (30)'], ['43 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['44 10-11am', ''], ['44 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]
```

its just the same (minus the spaces) but now =

print newrooms[3] prints ... "4"

all the code here =

```
print newrooms[3]
print newrooms
newrooms = re.sub(r'\s+', " ", str(newrooms))
print newrooms[3]
print newrooms
```

Why does the list now not act like a list ?

OK guys, I see, I was converting the whole list to a string with str(newrooms), what i should be doing is ..

```
 print newrooms[3]
    print newrooms
    for obj in newrooms:
        obj[0] = re.sub(r'\s+', " ", (obj[0]))
    print newrooms[3]
    print newrooms
```

Comment: when you encounter these kind of situations use `type` to see if anything changes. When you apply your regex the list becomes a string instead.

Comment: ...because it's **not a list?**

Comment: @Hugo more specifically when the OP applies `str(newrooms)` it becomes a string...

Comment: `re.sub` returns a string. Strings are a list of characters, so it is acting like a list

Comment: Hugo, you are right ... I have been using pycharm and should have kept an eye on the variables.. its quite obvious if i do.

Answer (score 4):

After

```
newrooms = re.sub(r'\s+', " ", str(newrooms))
```

`newrooms`, formerly a `list()`, becomes a string.

```
print newrooms[3]
```

prints the 4th character in that string. Python is ducktyping variables, so each variable flexibly adapts to what you store in it.

Answer (score 1):

You convert the `list` `newrooms` to a single string in this line:

```
newrooms = re.sub(r'\s+', " ", str(newrooms))
```

So it is just one string and not a list anymore. 
What you want to do is to apply the substitution on the single elements of the list:

```
newrooms = [
    [re.sub(r'\s+', " ", elem) for elem in sublist]
    for sublist in newrooms
]
```

This results in:

```
>>> newrooms[3]
['9 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to replace sequences of repeated whitespace with a single blank for each string in a lists of lists.

What you actually do is convert the list to a string and then do the substituting operation.

Here's what happens - I will use a shortened version of your original list for readability:

```
>>> import re
>>> newrooms = [['4      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['5      10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]
>>> newrooms_str = str(newrooms)
>>> newrooms_str
"[['4      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['5      10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]"
>>> newrooms_str = re.sub(r'\s+', " ", newrooms_str)
>>> newrooms_str
"[['4 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['5 10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]"
>>> newrooms_str[3]
'4'
```

As you can see, you are passing a string to `re.sub`, which returns a string. The fourth character of that string is the character `'4'` which you see when you do `newrooms_str[3]`.

In order to get your desired result, you need to operate on the *individual* strings in your list of lists:

```
>>> newrooms
[['4      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['5      10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]
>>> newrooms = [[re.sub(r'\s+', " ", string) for string in sublist] for sublist in newrooms]
>>> newrooms
[['4 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['5 10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]
>>> newrooms[1]
['5 10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.join` and `str.split` operating on each string in each sublist not convert the list to a string:

```
l = [['4      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['5      10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['8      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['9      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['10      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['10      11-12pm', 'MR251 (22)'], ['12      10-11am', 'MR107 (63)'], ['12      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['17      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['18      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['19      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['19      11-12pm', 'MR265 (24)'], ['20      10-11am', 'CB203 (26)'], ['20      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['27      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['28      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['29      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['42      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['42       2-4pm                MA ONLY', 'MR252 (30)'], ['43      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['44      10-11am', ''], ['44      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]

l[:] = [[" ".join(s.split()) for s in sub] for sub in l]

from pprint import  pprint as pp
```

Output will be a list:

```
[['4 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['5 10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['8 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['9 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['10 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['10 11-12pm', 'MR251 (22)'],
 ['12 10-11am', 'MR107 (63)'],
 ['12 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['17 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['18 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['19 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['19 11-12pm', 'MR265 (24)'],
 ['20 10-11am', 'CB203 (26)'],
 ['20 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['27 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['28 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['29 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['42 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['42 2-4pm MA ONLY', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['43 10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'],
 ['44 10-11am', ''],
 ['44 11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns unexpected result, because you convert list to the string before replacing. Try this instead:

```
import re
newrooms = [['4      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['5      10.30-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['8      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['9      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['10      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['10      11-12pm', 'MR251 (22)'], ['12      10-11am', 'MR107 (63)'], ['12      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['17      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['18      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['19      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['19      11-12pm', 'MR265 (24)'], ['20      10-11am', 'CB203 (26)'], ['20      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['27      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['28      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['29      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['42      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)'], ['42       2-4pm                MA ONLY', 'MR252 (30)'], ['43      10-11am', 'MR252 (30)'], ['44      10-11am', ''], ['44      11-12pm', 'MR252 (30)']]

newrooms = [[re.sub(r'\s+', " ", room) for room in rooms] for rooms in newrooms]
print newrooms[3]
```